# Azure Sign Ins REST API - risk Detection type is not available in Sign Ins

Tags: azure, rest, microsoft-graph-api, signing

I am trying to retrieve the Sign-ins having both normal successful Sign-ins and Risky Sign-ins. In Risky Sign-in cases, I couldn't retrieve the certain Detection Type which is used to categorize the types of Risky Sign in events.

For example, In Risk detections,

[image: Risk detection log image containing detection type and requestId]

same sign-in event retrieved via REST API

[image: Sign in Log retrieved via REST API]

Password spray risk event is categorized as Anonymous IP Address.

we always get AnonymousIP and never get other types

Is I need to use only Risk Detections API to retrieve these events else is it possible to retrieve via Sign Ins REST API ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried with this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/riskdetection-list?view=graph-rest-1.0): `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identityProtection/riskDetections?$filter=activity eq 'signin'`?

Comment: Yes, I have seen those details in RiskDetections API but not in SignIns API. 

So we have to send a separate request to fetch these risk detection types?

Comment: It seems better to use **List riskDetections** with `$filter=activity eq 'signin'` than **List signIns**.